# Check before inserting values in the table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have created two tables: Account and Loan

- In Account table I have `Acc_id` as primary key.
- In Loan table I have `Loan_id` as primary key and `Acc_id` as foreign key referencing the `Acc_id` in the Account table.

Now I have inserted 5 records in Account table..

```
101 YEARLY                  BEN                             21.12.2012
102 YEARLY                  PARKER                          31.07.2013
103 HALFYEARLY              MARY                            26.04.2013
104 TWOYEARS                OSBORN                          01.01.2014
105 TWOYEARS                HARRY                           04.06.2015
106 YEARLY                  PENNY                           25.12.2013
```

Now I have to insert values in loan table.

eg: `insert into loan values((203,'PARKER','500$',103(Ac_id),'25.11.2014');`

Now in the above query I have given Ben's `Acc_no` incorrectly. I have entered the `acc_no` of Mary, but it will be inserted successfully.

I need a procedure to prevent this from happening, can anyone tell me if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the data design - your loan table shouldn't have the name of the account holder in it - this is redundant.

If you want to check you can create a procedure such as,

```
create proc insertLoan
(    
    @accid int, 
    @accholder varchar(50), 
    @amount money    
)
as
begin
    if (exists (select * from accounts where id =@accid and accountname = @accholder))
    begin
        insert loans (accid, amount) values (@accid, @amount)
    end
    else
    begin
        raiserror ('mismatched account details',15,1)
    end
end
```

Comment: In loan table also I have the Name of customers as cus_name.

Comment: @RamMessi See above: "your loan table shouldn't have the name of the account holder in it".

Comment: Now i want to throw error if I insert incorrect acc_id for a customer in loan table..

Comment: Thanks, So  U say that the field name cus_name should not be used in loan table?. I am a begginer so pls guide

Comment: :Thanks, So U say that the field name cus_name should not be used in loan table?. I am a begginer so pls guide